# Как прибить футер к низу (шаблончик резиновый)?

Tags: html, дизайн, css

Уже и так и сяк, что-то я никак его не прижму, куда надо, вот **html**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class="header">LOGO my Site.php</div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="footer">World &copy; TM</div>
</div>
```

А вот **css**

```
* { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100%; 
}
.wrapper {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #444555;
}

.header { 
 text-align: center; 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 width: 80%; 
 height: 5%; 
 color: white; 
 background-color: darkBlue; 
 }
 .content {
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #FFBBAA;
 }

 .container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #00008B;
      width: 80%;
      background-color: #FFBBAA;
 }

 .footer {
     position: relative; 
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 80%;
     height: 10%;
     clear: both;
     border: 1px solid yellow;
     background-color: lightblue;
     text-align: center;
 }
```

P.S. [Шаблон на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/9KBDy/), имеется в виду сделать так, чтобы он, как и верхнее меню, был, стандартно никаких белых краев снизу чтобы не было при ресайзе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если сами ещё не умеете, то используйте [онлайн генератор](http://csstemplater.com/), и не просто создать шаблон, но и разобраться в его CSS

P.S. [Держите ваш футер](http://jsfiddle.net/9KBDy/3/), хотя это бред изначально и могу предположить, что в дальнейшем у вас еще бока вылазить будут.

HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class="header">LOGO my Site.php</div>
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <div>World &copy; TM</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #444555;

}

.header { text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; width: 80%; height: 5%; color: white; background-color: darkBlue; }
.content {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #FFBBAA;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #00008B;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #FFBBAA;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #444555;
}
.footer div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: у вас футер "прибит" с другой стороны - снаружи страницы, т.е. за 100% о чем свидетельствует скроллинг. проблема в ``* {height:100%;}``

Comment: Я исхожу из того, что дал автор. Если бы он попросил сделать изначально и по-уму, то и расклад бы был другой. Да в общем-то, за всё время автор даже не отозвался... уехал наверно))

Comment: Спасибо, приехал!

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [тут](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/karkas-verstki/podval-k-nizu.html). Там хорошо написано про это дело. Там есть два метода. Кому что понравится. Мне по душе второй.